# Read KML from powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, kml

I have kml (xml). I want to read it and further process it. 
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
 <Document><Placemark> 
 <Point> 
 <coordinates> 30.142550,49.797350,0 </coordinates> 
 </Point> 
 </Placemark><Placemark> 
 <Point> 
 <coordinates> 30.142533,49.797333,0 </coordinates> 
 </Point> 
 </Placemark><Placemark> 
 <Point> 
 <coordinates> 30.142517,49.797283,0 </coordinates> 
 </Point> 
 </Placemark></Document> 
 </kml>
```

And I'm trying to read it:

```
Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath -Namespace $XmlNamespace | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
$Path = "D:\temp\test\4.kml"
$xpath = "kml/Document/Placemark/Point"
$XmlNamespace = @{ default = '"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"'; };
Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath -Namespace $XmlNamespace | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

But there is no result...
Why?

Comment: You are using something arbitrary for the default namespace (default). You need to then prefix all of your nodes with that name --> `$xpath = "default:kml/default:Document/default:Placemark/default:Point"`. Also, your name space definition does not need to include literal quotes. Just use `$XmlNamespace = @{ default = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the default namespace and have chosen to name it (default), you need to then prefix all of your nodes with that name. Also, your name space definition does not need to include literal quotes.

```
$Path = "D:\temp\test\4.kml"
$xpath = "default:kml/default:Document/default:Placemark/default:Point"
$XmlNamespace = @{ default = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}
Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $Xpath -Namespace $XmlNamespace |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

From [Select-Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-6), the description of `-Namespace` says the following:

> When the XML uses the default namespace, which begins with xmlns, use
>   an arbitrary key for the namespace name. You cannot use xmlns. In the
>   XPath statement, prefix each node name with the namespace name and a
>   colon, such as //namespaceName:Node.